# LARAVEL FFMpeg: Unable to save frame error

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

When I'm trying to save my thumbnail, I'm getting "Unable to save frame" error.

I'm using https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg  Laravel-ffmpeg package, AWS S3 server.

My code:

```
Route::get('/thumbnail', function() {
    $file = FFMpeg::fromDisk('s3')
    ->open('/videos/71239_1598846328_p.mp4')
    ->getFrameFromSeconds(10)
    ->export()
    ->toDisk('s3')
    ->save('/videos/thumb.png');
    return "ok";
});
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that the folder path where you want to save the thumbnail exist and have the write permission.